# Matrix in "slash" order

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Given two positive numbers `N >= 2` and `N <= 100` create a matrix which follows the following rules:

- First Number starts at position `[0,0]`
- Second Number starts at position `[0,1]`
- Third number goes below First Number (position `[1,0]`)
- Following numbers goes in "slash" direction
- Range of numbers used is `[1, N1 * N2]`. So, numbers goes from starting 1 to the result of the multiplication of both inputs.

**Input**

- Two numbers `N >= 2` and `N <= 100`. First number is the amount of rows, Second number the amount of columns.

**Output**

- Matrix. (Can be outputted as a multidimensional array or a string with line breaks)

**Example:**

Given numbers `3 and 5` output:

```
1   2   4   7   10
3   5   8   11  13
6   9   12  14  15
```

Given numbers `2 and 2`

```
1   2
3   4
```

Given Numbers `5 and 5`

```
1   2   4   7   11
3   5   8   12  16
6   9   13  17  20
10  14  18  21  23
15  19  22  24  25
```

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Btw, is there a better name for this challenge? I dont know how to call it.

Comment: Can we use 0 indexing for any of the numbers?

Comment: @JoKing No. Must start at 1.

Comment: [Very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/155927/42963).

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Perhaps a better term for the order is "diagonals"? Personally, I'd call it a "zig-zag", because it reminds me of Cantor's Zig-Zag proof, but that might confusing.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz anti-diagonal is the term for the other diagonal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
pSÞỤs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78g@PC8h7uXFP8/vNxI3/1R05qsR437Dm07tO3/f2MdBVMdBSMwAjJMAQ)

#### How it works

```
pSÞỤs  Main link. Left argument: n. Right argument: k

p      Take the Cartesian product of [1, ..., n] and [1, ..., k], yielding
       [[1, 1], [1, 2], ..., [n, k-1], [n, k]].
 SÞ    Sort the pairs by their sums.
       Note that index sums are constant on antidiagonals.
   Ụ   Grade up, sorting the indices of the sorted array of pairs by their values.
    s  Split the result into chunks of length k.
```

Comment: Damn. Mine is 200+ bytes. Can you add some explanation pls?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: God damn it, Dennis. Also, good job.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Looks like you're not using Jelly. Some languages are verbose by default, don't worry about that.

Comment: Wow, it is too "closely related". That's identical to the first link in [miles' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155927/minimally-sort-a-list-into-a-matrix/155942#155942). Consider upvoting both. :)

Comment: I think it might be possible to do this with `<atom><atom>¥þ` but I can't find the right combination. [`oþ++þ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z//8D5t7cP7/h9efmir@///pv@NAQ) is close but doesn't quite get there

Comment: Seems like this answer won.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what `Ụ` does. So up to that point for say a matrix dim(2,3) you would have `[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]` which you sort by the sum of their pairs. I assume that the sort 1.is low to high 2. tie leaves first appearance first giving `[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3]]`. Am I right up to here? What happens after this step?

Comment: @akozi So far, so good. The indices of the sorted array are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. `Ụ` sorts this array, using the key that maps `1` to `[1, 1]`, `2` to `[1, 2]`, `3` to `[2, 1]`, etc. Essentially, this finds the index of each pair from the sorted-by-sums array in the sorted-lexicographically array

Comment: So you map the numbers 1-n*k to the unsorted list based on the sorted list then split the unsorted list back into rows of length k?

Comment: @akozi Basically, yes.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
def f(n,k):M=[(t//k+t%k,t)for t in range(n*k)];return zip(*k*[map([M,*sorted(M)].index,M)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNCoMwEIXXeorZiDNpqKB0Y@kRPIG4EExaCZ2EdKQ/l08N7WrevPfxhbfcPHcpLcaCRdaO@uEyojSNO0jltJD1EQRWhjjz1SArR9M5Gtkiw2cNqJwa73PAcdDq4aOYBQeajisv5qX3RCkbdjU4yhrsNJxIA7Ya2nxP@e/LImPRPzNjf/heFiGuLFhX7QY1KHBQZYjK/0DpCw)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>101</s> <s>60</s> 54 bytes

```r
function(M,N)matrix(rank(outer(1:M,1:N,"+"),,"l"),M,N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NXx08zN7GkKLNCoygxL1sjv7QktUjD0MpXx9DKT0dJW0lTR0cpB0iCFP5P0zDWMdXkStMwBVL/AQ)

*Thanks to @nwellnhof for the suggestion of `rank`*

Ports [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163275/67312).

Old answer, 101 bytes:

```r
function(M,N)matrix(unsplit(lapply(split(1:(M*N),unlist(split(x,x))),rev),x<-outer(1:M,1:N,"+")),M,N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoAgEEX3nSJazdS0iGgTXUHvIJEgmImNYac3o1af//7jh6zrpc86upXN4UCQxF1xMAmiO701DFZ5b2/4yjCDaCVSdNac/MNECREpbBdSWvoj8haKKWiYJTVdU7b3N2sYacJKw1QiPw)

`split` is doing most of the work here; possibly there's a golfier algorithm but this definitely works.

Explanation:

```r
function(M,N){
x <- outer(1:M,1:N,"+")			# create matrix with distinct indices for the antidiagonals
idx <- split(x,x)			# split into factor groups
items <- split(1:(M*N),unlist(idx))	# now split 1:(M*N) into factor groups using the groupings from idx
items <- lapply(items,rev)		# except that the factor groups are
					# $`2`:1, $`3`:2,3, (etc.) but we need
                                        # $`2`:1, $`3`:3,2, so we reverse each sublist
matrix(unsplit(items,x),M,N)		# now unsplit to rearrange the vector to the right order
					# and construct a matrix, returning the value
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBTsMwDIbP7VNYg0MCAWmbdql4he0ZlrVuF6lLKsfZihDPPtysEwJxoJfIbv4v/n/TtYW3l2ubfM0ueLU1O/1RjtKDkBhJLautWVY7s3he6KIoHqAmtIxwskxuhIvjIzQushMAON@4GiO0gYCPCNaza5ztgrd9LF2TuXHoHavRjDdeLkXJAVpbsyg7CmmQ64yn@C1YVmr7tNMm@V6eUwLTWuQ@XGbEfOEPFKTofJcnyg0pZEYKJxDK9zu9HYb@XeXaEJ71NB6ONQ4sWssZ8BNsCcuiyD4e96t9tTRyrvfVyqwNKOT6VcMhMVwQPGJTwj@/X7i1WRmIYcLIXEgRAW19hJgOUxjlbRkq@VtUNwejNtM2izmk@SdIOLJBIus7zI7OmB1Jf6rIdUeGQA3S3Zn1DdTBR6YkO7bz6o1gOJG/J3u2fcLy89qqtdnoslUbOa5f) -- you can use wrap a `print` around any of the right-hand sides of the assignments `<-` to see the intermediate results without changing the final outcome, as `print` returns its input.

Comment: Can you add some explanation pls?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz added. If there's anything unclear, let me know and I'll try and clarify.

Comment: `rank(x,1,"f")` is 2 bytes shorter than `order(order(x))`.

Comment: @nwellnhof oh, very nice, but using `rank(x,,"l")` will get rid of the `t` as well.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 10, <s>121</s> <s>120</s> <s>109</s> 105 bytes

```java
m->n->{var R=new int[m][n];for(int i=0,j,v=0;i<m+n;)for(j=++i<n?0:i-n;j<i&j<m;)R[j][i-++j]=++v;return R;}
```

-11 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-4 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZExa8MwEIX3/oqbioVlYRKyRLZLl0KHLsloNKiOE6RaZyPLLiHkt7tyIkhSOhSEuMd7h96HtBxlondfU9XIvocPqfD0BNA76VQF2rtscKph@wErp1pkb2HI3tHVh9rS/4UUulKUoiigghwmkxSYFKdRWtjkWH9ffCNKFHzf2sgrUHlKNR3zlKvMxMjJbOg8jlWGL@laJch1pp51ZjjZlFqUKoljLXxg5LZ2g0XY8PPEPY0/3fDZeKDANbZqB8azRltnFR5KIcmMDeDq3kVLuiL8Jld0eS8XdPHorh7dX7vX8Pla4/79iz@TIp1vExoEfl9pXTHZdc0xQhIGQ8glA7A99q42rB0c6zyBazC6/cOrtfLYM9de6SJJQqU/tkK78/QD)

**Explanation:**

```java
m->n->{                // Method with two integer parameters and integer-matrix return-type
  var R=new int[m][n]; //  Result-matrix of size `m` by `n`
  for(int i=0,j,       //  Index integers, starting at 0
          v=0;         //  Count integer, starting at 0
      i<m+n;)          //  Loop as long as `i` is smaller than `m+n`
    for(j=++i<n?0      //   Set `j` to 0 if `i+1` is smaller than `n`
               :i-n;   //   or to the difference between `i` and `n` otherwise
        j<i&j<m;)      //   Inner loop `j` until it's equal to either `i` or `m`,
                       //   so basically check if it's still within bounds:
      R[j][i-++j]=++v; //    Add the current number to cell `j, i-(j+1)`
  return R;}           //  Return the result-matrix
```

Comment: I realized this takes columns first and then rows.

Comment: @Luis I think it's convention to take coordinates as `x,y`/`width,height`

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVCxasMwFNz7FW8qErZFSMhS2YYuhQ5dktF4UB07SLWejfzsEkK@3ZUTQVLoUJDEO92Ju5NRk0rM4WuuWjUM8KE0np8ABlKkKzCeFSPpVjQjVqQ7FG9hSN@R6mPt4v@JNFJRFmWeQwUZzDbJMcnPk3Kwy7D@vvK2LLCUTeeYR6CzVTz5baRObYRSRxFfOJOtpEkzLY2/0A3TiUnx2aSW7wpTFh6WWRRN0tU0OoSdvMzSN/KrHz9bXyp0mzp9AOv7sj05jceiVHypDkD1QGwTb7m8w228eYTreP2bvYkvN6NHhyu/9MF4OW3wCC296UslVN@3J4Y8DJbzqwZgfxqotqIbSfQ@I7XI7r/96pw6DYK6W36meIj0x6uQ7jL/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
$1(+/:@;)</.@i.
```

-4 more bytes for this solution by miles. Thanks!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F/FUENb38rBWtNGX88hU@@/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@QpqCsYIpjGmkYARjmgJF/wMA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>22</strike> 19 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog!

```
,$[:>:@/:@/:@,+/&i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9HJdrKzspBH4x0tPXVMvX@a3Ip6Smop9nqqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkKxgrpCmYQphGQKYRhGkKFv0PAA)

An implementation of Dennis' fantastic Jelly solution in J.

### Explanation:

Dyadic verb, takes left and right argument (m f n)

`+/&i.` creates lists 0..m-1 and 0..n-1 and makes an addition table for them:

```
   3 +/&i. 5
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
```

`[:>:@/:@/:@,` flattens the table and grades the list twice and adds 1 to it:

```
   3 ([:>:@/:@/:@,+/&i.) 5
1 2 4 7 10 3 5 8 11 13 6 9 12 14 15
```

`,$` reshapes the list back into mxn table:

```
   3 (-@],\[:>:@/:@/:@,+/&i.) 5
1 2  4  7 10
3 5  8 11 13
6 9 12 14 15
```

Comment: ``-@],\`` → ``,$`` for −3 bytes.

Comment: @FrownyFrog - Of course, I feel stupid, it's so obvous now. Thank you!

Comment: 15 bytes `$1(+/:@;)</.@i.` with input as an array `[r, c]`

Comment: @miles: Very cool, thanks! I tried `/.` but could't achieve your result :)

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, 38 or 22 bytes

Prompts for integer input column then row:

```
m[⍋+⌿1+(r,c)⊤m-1]←m←⍳(c←⎕)×r←⎕⋄(r,c)⍴m
```

or:

```
(r,c)⍴⍋⍋,(⍳r←⎕)∘.+⍳c←⎕
```

based on Dennis's double application of grade up. Missed that :(

Comment: Sorry for the question but is there somewhere I can test it?

Comment: @Luis felipe De jesus Munoz No problem. APL+WIN is not available on line but you can test it on the Dyalog website at http://tryapl.org/ if you replace the ⎕ characters with the integers of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```apl
{⍵⍴⍋⍋∊+/↑⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79ZHvVse9XaDUEeXtv6jtomPejcDhWv//3/UO1fBNzEzTyGtNC@5JDM/T0GjuDQpN7O4GMjW5OJKU3jUNkEBnxlcXCAzQlKLSxSSE4tTi4EGpBYkFiWWpCqUZ5ZkKCQq5GTmpSok5@eVAO3JzEtX0HjUNxVo6qPeNZpgG4wVTLngQkC@kYIRCt9UwRQA)

-2 thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn), due to his clever usage of `↑⍳`.

Based off of Dennis's 5-byte Jelly solution.

Comment: `∘.+⌿⍳¨⍵` -> `+/↑⍳⍵`

Comment: @ngn Wow, that's a clever usage of `⍳` combined with `↑`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>73</s> 67 bytes

Count elements in rows above: `Min[j+k,#2]~Sum~{k,i-1}`

Count elements on the current row and below: `Max[j-k+i-1,0]~Sum~{k,i,#}`

Put into a table and add 1. Voila:

```
1+Table[Min[j+k,#2]~Sum~{k,i-1}+Max[j-k+i-1,0]~Sum~{k,i,#},{i,#},{j,#2}]&
```

Update: I realized there is a shorter way to count all the positions ahead of a normally specified position in the matrix with just one sum over two dimensions:

```
Table[1+Sum[Boole[s-i<j-t||s-i==j-t<0],{s,#},{t,#2}],{i,#},{j,#2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQxKSc12lA7uDQ32ik/H8gu1s20ydItqakBMmxtgSwbg1id6mId5Vqd6hIdZaNaIC8TzMsC89T@BxRl5pVEp0Ub65jGxv4HAA)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b731A7JDEpJzXaNzMvOks7W0fZKLYuuDS3rjpbJ1PXsFbbN7EiOks3WxvI0TFASOko1@pUQ8gsoJ7aWLX/AUWZeSXRadHGOqaxsf8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

```
*L<DΣ¹LILâOsè}UΣXsè}Á>ô
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fy8fG5dziQzt9PH0OL/IvPryiNvTc4ggQfbjR7vCW//@NuUwB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 164 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
r=range
def h(x,y):
 a,i,k,j=-array([i//y+i%y for i in r(x*y)]),1,2,0
 while j<x+y:a[a==-j],i,k,j=r(i,k),k,k+sum(a==~j),j+1
 a.shape=x,y;return a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY07DsIwEER7n2IbJC9Z/qIBfBJEYQkHryGOtTgibrh6MBIFzXw00rxUsu/jbppa6TuIQ5cKcJd6yXMlRmy8OXV1LXg9UsGDAktMdwpmYUVs0WderUrDswJtL8DAEUSP84IXpA1taa3g5fnhIJzGphzs2RqzCJffiejqWOO9eQ6drts7IIVmUznLp7fJmYo9isuDRLBTEo5Ze/1VjmnIGpHgvwHitFf7Dw)

This is definitely not the shortest solution, but I thought it was a fun one.

Comment: `from numpy import*` and dropping both `n.` is slightly shorter. Also, you can drop the space at `) for`. And changing to Python 2 allows you to change `return a` to `print a` (in Python 3 it would be the same byte-count `print(a)`).

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of `import*`. I'll never beat Dennis' answer, so I'll stick to Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 76 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
{A,Bdim([A]
1X
For(E,1,B+A
For(D,1,E
If D≤A and E-D<B
Then
X[A](D,E-D+1
X+1X
End
End
End
[A]
```

Prompts for user input and returns the matrix in `Ans` and prints it.

TI-Basic is a [tokenized language](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens); all tokens used here are one byte, other than `[A]` which is 2 bytes.

Note: TI-Basic (at least on the TI-84 Plus CE) only supports matrices up to 99x99, and so does this program.

Explanation:

```
Prompt A,B        # 5 bytes, prompt for user input
{A,Bdim([A]      # 9 bytes, make the matrix the right size
1X               # 4 bytes, counter variable starts at 1
For(E,1,B+A       # 9 bytes, Diagonal counter, 1 to A+B-1, but we can over-estimate since we have to check later anyway.
For(D,1,E         # 7 bytes, Row counter, 1 to diagonal count
If D≤A and E-D<B  # 10 bytes, Check if we are currently on a valid point in the matrix
Then              # 2 bytes, If so,
X[A](D,E-D+1     # 13 bytes, Store the current number in the current point in the matrix
X+1X             # 6 bytes, Increment counter
End               # 2 bytes, End dimension check if statement
End               # 2 bytes, End row for loop
End               # 2 bytes, End dimension for loop
[A]               # 2 bytes, Implicitly return the matrix in Ans and print it
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
def f(b,a):i=1;o=[];exec"if b:o+=[],;b-=1\nfor l in o:k=len(l)<a;l+=[i]*k;i+=k\n"*a*b;print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDsIgEADP@opNT9Cuh2J6AXmJ7QEU4gayNE0P@nqE02SSmf13fgqrWt8hQhQendRkZ1PsczPhG14DRfC6TM3R@JudV47lgAzEUHSyObDI8uFMbgltYzI02bTyMLrRm/0gPqHUvghGSLJ/4o6wSAShEFTn0l1fL7E1SdY/)

Semi-Ungolfed version:

```python
def f(b,a):
    i=1
    o=[]
    for _ in range(a*b)
        if b:
            o+=[[]]
            b-=1

        for l in o:
            if len(l)<a:
                l+=[i]
                i+=1
    print o
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Hardly elegant, but gets the job done. Working with 2D data in Japt is tricky.

```js
;N×Ç<U©Ap[] A®Ê<V©Zp°T
A

;                      // Set alternative default vars where A is an empty array.
 N×Ç                   // Multiply the inputs and map the range [0..U*V).
    <U                 // If the current item is less than the second input,
      ©Ap[]            // add a new empty subarray into A.
            A®         // Then, for each item in A,
              Ê<V      // if its length is less than the first input,
                 ©Zp°T // Add the next number in the sequence to it.
A                      // Output the results, stored in A.
```

I added the `-Q` flag in TIO for easier visualization of the results, it doesn't affect the solution.
Bit off one byte thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qYXB0//87TsOXw4c8VcKpQXBbXSBBwq7DijxWwqlacMKwVApB//8zIDUKLVE)

Comment: Speaking of `×`, you can replace `*V ` with `N×`.

Comment: @Oliver And here I was, thinking that shortcut is handy, but not a common use case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 103 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,e=[...Array(b)].map(_=>[]))=>f=(x=0,y=i=0)=>(x<a&y<b&&(e[y][x]=++i),x?f(--x,++y):y>a+b?e:f(++y,0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpNCoMwEEDh28gM@UEo3Vgn0o2XCKFMbCwWaySWkpzeZvk@3pt/fExp2b9qi89wjnQyGU8GAlmt9T0lLuDR6Q/v8CBjHcqZIFMrCy3UYl1zz03pfdNAsMXZ7EiIBWUeZlAqSyEKdsWw8EPoZqgpW0Q8b1PcjrgGvcYXjHBFuCBU/wM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```perl6
{($!={sort($_ Z=>1..*)>>.{*}})($!([X+] ^<<$_)).rotor(.[1])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwEEWvMpYgMzUMtFI3NjmHWGtxYUDRRqbdlJCzx2T1@O/zfk/5nNJ3g70DkwKqnQmLlxXVBFdjG@aarOVQx0j5xOFyGOHe92oiYvGrF@ShGSmm5bGByxnx279mrG5zRRoKwHkBPGrossBWQ1vYlX1Ofw)

Another port of Dennis' Jelly solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>142</s> 131 bytes

```java
X->Y->{var A=new int[X][Y];int E=1;for(int y=0;y<Y+X-1;y++)for(int x=0;x<X;x++){if(y-x<0|y-x>Y-1)continue;A[x][y-x]=E++;}return A;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVE9b4MwEN37K260xYfy0Sw1IDGkUodOWUDIg0tJ5JQYZI4UK@W3U0OokkodKlmnu/fOfvfOR3EW3vH9Y8hL0TTwKqS6PAA0KFDmcLSs36Is/X2rcpSV8p/nJHhRWBwK7f6vSSrMeMajCHIIYUi8KPWiy1loiENVfE58wrOUM5vBNlyyfaXJmJtwwUyQOom3ZMZx6A/eWbwLEtZZ7CL3xHhdsPiy0b68pHmlUKq2YHHW8cyiPNw6Dut1ga1WELN@YNanPXX7Vlqrs@NzJd/hZLdAdqilOmRc0HEhAFg0SNbuI2W3cuOu78uVu/rNbqayvwrdK0z86CJ1x5jMGrM3K/qU@6KuS0NSOicJpVMPwM40WJz8qkW/tjNiqcjtD2KthWl8rK7zE0Hnkf64NU/XD98)

**Explanation:**

```java
X->Y->{                            // Method with two integer parameters and integer-matrix return-type
    var A=new int[X][Y];           // The Matrix with the size of X and Y
    int E=1;                       // It's a counter
        for(int y=0;y<Y+X-1;y++)   // For each column plus the number of rows minus one so it will run as long as the bottom right corner will be reached
            for(int x=0;x<X;x++){  // For each row
                if(y-x<0|y-x>Y-1)  // If the cell does not exist becouse it's out of range
                    continue;      // Skip this loop cycle
                A[x][y-x]=E++;     // Set the cell to the counter plus 1
            }
    return A;                      // Return the filled Array
}
```

*Big thank to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) because I didn't know how to run my code on [tio](https://tio.run/).
Some code like the header and footer are stolen from him. [-> His answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163276/75908)*

Comment: 119 bytes: https://tio.run/##jVA9b4MwFNz7K143W4CVj2apAYkhlTp0ygJCHlwCkVNikDEpVprfTh3iKqnUoZL15Hv37Lt7e37kwX77MRY17zp440KeHgA6zbUoYG9Z0mtRk6qXhRaNJC/uEr5KXe5K5f9vSEids5zFMRQQwZgGcRbEpyNXkESy/Jz4lOUZo1WjkEWwjua@iWbUhJmXBnNqPA//cIPtD2FKB9sTFXpEJhjC2Zet9ts5xkk@sNwiFq09j6pS90pCQs8jtdnsafv32sZzKY@N2MLBJkcbrYTc5YzjyxIAdNlptPSfML3Blb@8hwt/8ZtdTfB8FbpXmPiL@8y/1NRpuExW9LkgvG1rgzLsLinG0wzAxnS6PJCm16S1HnUt0W3viVLcdEQ3V/@IY2fpj1fO3Xn8Bg

Comment: [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZDBa4MwGMXv@yu@0zAkhq5dL406PHSww069KJJDZm1JZ6PE2BlK/3YXrdAWdhiE8D3eF9775SBOwj9sv/u8FE0Dn0Kq8xNAY4SRORycS1sjS7prVW5kpej7NAQfyhT7QpP/LUllMp7xKIIcQugTP0r96HwSGuJQFT@jn/As5WxXac8pWIcvxIYz0jGMbZDihKHB6kIn3mYr66esC5LnLrAMxVnHM@tj3PFwjTHThWm1gphdeuZo3Knbr9IBTVynSm7h6Fi9jdFS7TMu0IANYIrGeAvyithNLsniXs7J/NFdjvJyDbpPGP2BJSXDnUwZE6ELXeVU1HVpvRRNQ4LQuAOwsY0pjrRqDa1dR1Mq7/bTsdbCNtRU1/6eQFOlP15N7S79Lw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
ṠCoηÖ¤×,ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9odXNr///huaBDb863w5bCpMOXLOG4o////zP/NQ) Most of the heavy lifting is done by `×`, which creates pairs in the desired order so that it can support infinite lists.

#### Explanation

```
CηÖ×,ḣ²ḣ⁰⁰  (Expanded; let N and K denote the arguments.)
 ηÖ          Take the list of indices of the sorted values of
   ×,         the list of all pairs taken from
     ḣ²        the range from 1 to N and
       ḣ⁰      the range from 1 to K, and
C        ⁰  cut it into lengths of K.
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 115 bytes

a pretty lazy approach; probably not the shortest possible.

```php
function($w,$h){for(;$i++<$h*$w;$r[+$y][+$x]=$i,$x--&&++$y<$h||$x=++$d+$y=0)while($x>=$w|$y<0)$y+=!!$x--;return$r;}
```

anonymous function, takes width and height as parameters, returns 2d matrix

[try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67d5f8de325e9267933c5eeb634f3d8f07cece55)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>108</strike> <strike>105</strike> <strike>101</strike> 100 bytes

```javascript
n=>(l=>{for(r=[];i<n*n;n*~-n/2+2>i?l++:l--*y++)for(T=y,t=l;t--;)r[T]=[...r[T++]||[],++i]})(y=i=0)||r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDsIgFADQ3ZMAv6Dp4CB@vEQ3wtDUYjDkYygxIaJXR93e8O7zc96WHB5FUrqu3WMnNCyiefmUWUbrdDiTIE3iI2k/wmjCJQKcopSiAvB/m7AOBaMuUmqe7eTQKqV@AHCtWTcABPfmrGLAA28t9yXRluKqYroxz46c7/oX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 45 bytes

```
{Chop[Grade//2<|Flat!Table[`+,1:_2,1:_],_]+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7v9o5I78g2r0oMSVVX9/IpsYtJ7FEMSQxKSc1OkFbx9Aq3ghExOrEx2ob1v73S01NKY5WKShITo/lqlYIKMrMK4mOj9dRUNK1U4q1VnDJLC7ISayMTnNwiAdyIfKxCrUKtnYK0VwKQBBtrGMaqwNhGukYwZimQFGu2P8A)

Anonymous lambda, where paramaters are switched. This can be fixed for +1 byte, by prepending `~` to the program. The test suite does this already.

### Explanation

This approach is similar to the [J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163281/31957) and the [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163275/31957).

The first idea is to generate a table of values:

```
Table[`+,1:_2,1:_]
```

This generates an addition table using ranges of both input parameters. For input `[5, 3]`, this gives:

```
A> Table[`+,1:3,1:5]
 2 3 4 5 6
 3 4 5 6 7
 4 5 6 7 8
```

Then, we flatten this with `Flat!`:

```
A> Flat!Table[`+,1:3,1:5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Using the approach in the J answer, we can grade the array (that is, return indices of sorted values) twice, with `Grade//2`:

```
A> Grade//2<|Flat!Table[`+,1:3,1:5]
[0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12, 5, 8, 11, 13, 14]
```

Then, we need to chop the values up correctly, as in the Jelly answer. We can cut every `_` elements to do this:

```
A> Chop[Grade//2<|Flat!Table[`+,1:3,1:5],5]
 0 1  3  6  9
 2 4  7 10 12
 5 8 11 13 14
```

Then, we just need to compensate for the 0-indexing of Attache with `+1`:

```
A> Chop[Grade//2<|Flat!Table[`+,1:3,1:5],5]+1
 1 2  4  7 10
 3 5  8 11 13
 6 9 12 14 15
```

And thus we have the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 259 bytes

So I did this a weird way. I noticed that there were two patterns in the way the array forms.

**The first** is how the top rows pattern has the difference between each term increasing from 1 -> h where h is the height and l is the length. So I construct the top row based on that pattern

For a matrix of dim(3,4) giving a `max RoC = 3` We will see the top row of the form

```
1, (1+1), (2+2), (4+3) = 1, 2, 4, 7
```

Suppose instead that the dim(3,9) giving a `max RoC = 3` we will instead see a top row of

```
`1, (1+1), (2+2), (4+3), (7+3), (10+3), (13+3), (16+3), (19+3) = 1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22
```

**The second** pattern is how the rows change from one another. If we consider the matrix:

```
1   2   4   7   11
3   5   8   12  16
6   9   13  17  20
10  14  18  21  23
15  19  22  24  25
```

and subtract each row from the row below (ignoring the extra row) we get

```
2 3 4 5 5
3 4 5 5 4
4 5 5 4 3
5 5 4 3 2
```

Upon seeing this matrix we can notice this matrix is the sequence `2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2` where by each row is 5 terms of this pattern shifted by 1 for each row. See below for visual.

```
         |2 3 4 5 5| 4 3 2
       2 |3 4 5 5 4| 3 2
     2 3 |4 5 5 4 3| 2
   2 3 4 |5 5 4 3 2|
```

So to get the final matrix we take our first row we created and output that row added with the 5 needed terms of this pattern.

This pattern will always have the characteristics of beginning `2-> max value` and ending `max value -> 2` where the `max value = min(h+1, l)` and the number of times that the max value will appear is `appearances of max = h + l -2*c -2` where `c = min(h+1, l) - 2`

So in whole my method of creating new rows looks like

```
1  2  3  7  11 +      |2 3 4 5 5|4 3 2  = 3  5  8  12 16

3  5  8  12 16 +     2|3 4 5 5 4|3 4 2  = 6  9  13 17 20

6  9  13 17 20 +   2 3|4 5 5 4 3|4 2    = 10 14 18 21 23

10 14 18 21 23 + 2 3 4|5 5 4 3 2|       = 15 19 22 24 25
```

Relevant code below. It didn't end up being short but I still like the method.

```python
o,r=len,range
def m(l,h):
 a,t=[1+sum(([0]+[x for x in r(1,h)]+[h]*(l-h))[:x+1]) for x in r(l)],min(l,h+1);s,c=[x for x in r(2,t)],[a[:]]
 for i in r(h-1):
  for j in r(o(a)):
   a[j]+=(s+[t]*(l+h-2*(t-2)-2)+s[::-1])[0+i:l+i][j]
  c+=[a[:]]
 for l in c:print(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BbsMgEETvfAVHNguSTdsLEV@COCDHKUQYR5hK7tc7a7uHVEJa7dthZp6/Lc7lY9tmWW0ei6yhfI/sNt75JLKMYBgPslnX4/IzCeE6j27l97nylafCq@hJRCz6i8gqAjizYu/hXZLByymVw@@6yMH@d9CykcAFZ7xnxyGdh6j6Pf9AjxPNIsDBeHAPj1Ys6NoejVHpi2hKAz1cnDGKWrgOk8mYPInp04D2PSbvnoN51lQaldwmqqKBnTtwNolP@UXzD9CuO6k72F4)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 20 bytes

```
õ ïVõ)ñx
£bYgUñ¹ÄÃòV
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDvVvUp8XgKo2JZZ1XxucTD8lY=&input=Myw1Ci1S)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 92 bytes

```hs
r=[1..]
(#)=take
n!k=[[sum$lookup(i,j)$zip[(i,j)|s<-r,i<-n#r,j<-k#r,i+j==s]r|j<-k#r]|i<-n#r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsMgEEX3OcWEuFBqhBK6096gJxApQgM1JkY02ZTc3ZrYQhddzf/z33zmqaPtxzGlIOSZMVXhhohF275ytRVSxnVC4zzb1WNDB4JexstDbZG3gRreuibQgbc2D3MahIgqbMWrrcQqTdo4EPCYK4BJ@9sdfDBuAQRdfcm7r5Of7ny/f3NRR8UuO6V@uVyCMSWGFOw/hVFJCcs4yzhH10KlNw)